# Error handling in unix shell ksh

Tags: unix, ksh

Can anyone guide to a document or explain on the below

- how to use error handling in ksh.
- How does Unix work on unhandled errors(like error happened in the
  subscript etc..).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `ksh` *man* page.

**Unhandled errors**

> Errors detected by the shell, such as syntax errors, cause the shell to return a **non-zero exit status**.  If the shell is being used
>   *non-interactively*, then **execution** of the  shell
>          file  is  **abandoned**  **UNLESS** the error occurs **inside** a **subshell** in which case the **subshell** is **abandoned**.

**Error handling**

*Basically* **check** exit/return codes to handle errors:

```
if [ $exit_code != 0 ]; then
  # Your error handler
fi
```

**Example**

```
test_handler() {
  ls file_not_present
  if [ $? -eq 2 ]; then 
    echo "Handler for No such file or directory"
  elif [ $? -ne 0]; then
    echo "Handler for any other exception"
  else
    echo "Succesful execution"
  fi
}
```

Will *throw*:

```
ls: cannot access non_file: No such file or directory
Handler for No such file or directory
```

But if the command does not exit:

```
test_handler() {
  l file_not_present
  if [ $? -eq 2 ]; then 
    echo "Handler for No such file or directory"
  elif [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Handler for any other exception"
  else
    echo "Succesful execution"
  fi
}
```

The output will be:

```
l: not found [No such file or directory]
Handler for any other exception
```

> The shell returns
>   the **exit status** of the **last command executed**
>          (see also the exit command above).  Run time errors detected by the shell are reported by printing the command or function name and
>   the error condition.  If the line number  that
>          the error occurred on is greater than one, then the line number is also printed in square brackets ([]) after the command or function
>   name.

Comment: Thanks. But what if we want to handle error inside the function itself. is it possible to check like a "try -- catch" as done in some other languages?

Comment: Hi @klashxx:  What i meant is - I have a function X written in a script Y and i don't want to exit Y if there is an UNHANDLED error occured in X. instead exit X

Comment: You will have to test every `command` / `cmd` executed in the function, the basic rule: `exit > 0` implies error handling.